# Why I can not see results of form data function in console NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to receive in result fields value to operate them a little down in the code But I have undefined in console.log Please explaine why and how I can get my fields down in the code

```
var multiparty = require('multiparty')

module.exports.login = function(req, res) {
    var form = new multiparty.Form();
 const result = form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
      console.log(err, fields, files);
        return fields
    })
console.log('result=>',result)//undefined

    res.send('Hello from Express!')
};
```

I understand that I need to use prommises but I dont know how, please show me by your code sample

```
    var multiparty = require('multiparty')

module.exports.login = function(req, res) {
    var form = new multiparty.Form();
 var result  = () => { form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
      console.log(err, fields, files);
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
       resolve(fields);

    })
})}
console.log('result=>',result.resolve)

    res.send('Hello from Express!')
};
```

Comment: Please show by code sample I can not understand I am beginer in JS

Answer (score 1):

Is undefined because function passed in parse method is callback and you can't get return from callback. try this

```
var multiparty = require('multiparty')
module.exports.login = function(req, res) {
    var form = new multiparty.Form();
    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
       console.log(err, fields, files);
       console.log('result=>',fields)

       res.send('Hello from Express!')
    })
};
```

Comment: May be I can put fields variable somewhere to use it after parse method ? As you can see I am trying to use prommises but no results in my case

Comment: in the parse callback function call another outside function that can save given argument from parse. create new function and call it. like save(fields)

Comment: Please show by the code I dont understand that

Comment: It would be easier if you take an intro course to javascript. Async is a broad topic and could be hard to explain in this site.

Comment: Please show how it can be done it is ineresting for me Thanks By Promise in callback

Comment: *"you can't get return from callback"* - This is not entirely true. The value returned by the callback function is passed to function/method that accepted callback. So it could be returned to you via the function that accepted the callback. `[1, 2, 3].map(nr => nr + 1)` is an good example of this. Here the return value of the provided callback is returned to you for each element. This is not the case for `parse` since the method always returns `undefined` (has no return value). Otherwise the answer is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `multiparty` and don't know if the callback provided is called synchronous or asynchronous. The shortest solution is still the [answer of Artur T](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55269611/3982562), simply moving all the code into the callback. However if the code gets more complex this might not be the best solution. You should also be on the lookout for [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/).

If the callback is called in a synchronous matter you can simply do the following:

```
var result,
    form = new multiparty.Form();

form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
  console.log(err, fields, files);
  result = fields;
  // ^ set the result variable instead of returning
});

// ...
```

If the callback is called in an asynchronous matter things get more complicated, and you have to wrap the callback into the promise creation.

```
var form = new multiparty.Form();

const result = new Promise(resolve => {
  form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
    console.log(err, fields, files);
    resolve(fields);
    //        ^ resolve the promise with fields as passed value
  });
});

result.then(fields => {
  console.log('result=>', fields);
  res.send('Hello from Express!');
});
```

Alternatively you can change your function into an `async` function (meaning the return value will be wrapped in a promise). Which is relatively new, but codes cleaner.

```
module.exports.login = async function(req, res) {
  //                     ^ notice the async keyword

  var form = new multiparty.Form();
  const result = await new Promise(resolve => {
    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
      console.log(err, fields, files);
      resolve(fields);
    });
  });

  console.log('result=>', result);
  res.send('Hello from Express!');
};
```

The whole structure can be simplified if you leave out the logging in-between.

```
const [err, fields, files] = await new Promise(resolve => 
  form.parse(req, (...args) => resolve(args)));
//                     ^                 ^
// collect all arguments into an array and use that as resolve value

// ...
```

For more explanation about [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) and [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) have a look at the documentation. This last example also uses [destructing assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).